# Software displaying the time of an NTP server

Tags: windows, windows-xp, mac, ntp

Is there any software that can display the time from an NTP server? Irregardless of what is going on with the time in the operating system itself. Like, just enter in the hostname of an NTP server and then a digital clock displaying what time it gets from it, staying in sync.

I'm using the [Meinberg NTP](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm) and I am getting a lot of stats from their [NTP Time Server Monitor](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/time-server-monitor.htm), but can't find the current time anywhere :p For some reason, I am not able to get the computer (running Windows XP, unfortunately) to sync with it or any NTP server so can't use the clock in windows. The servers that use this computer as their NTP server seems to be able to get a time from it though, but yeah... would be nice to see what time my NTP server actually have so I could at least try to see if two computers have the same time.

Looking for software running on either Windows XP or Mac OS X 10.4 or 10.5 (PPC).

Just to clearify: I don't want software that is an NTP server or that wants to set or show the time in the operating system. I want an NTP client that only asks an NTP server for the time, and then shows that time to me in a clear way.

Comment: is that the kind of software you're looking for? http://ntp-time-server.qarchive.org/ It works only on windows OS.

Comment: @r0ca: No, those looks like NTP servers. I'm looking for an NTP client of sorts. One that doesn't do much else than display the time it gets. In other words, doesn't do anything with the time on the current machine or listens to NTP requests from other computers et cetera. Just want something where I can see what time I get from an NTP server that is already set up and working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C:\> ntpdate -q -d ntp.example.net
```

Should be part of the Meinberg suite build and will give good information about what is not working without changing the clock.