# How do I get the current date according to an NTP server without setting it locally?

Tags: linux, centos, date, ntp, time-zone

I want to get the current date and time according to a remote NTP server, using Linux. I don't want to change the local time as a result; I just want to get the remote date, adjusted for the local time zone, printed out. The date returned must comply with the following criteria:

1. It needs to be reasonably accurate.
2. It needs to be adjusted for the timezone on the local system making the request.
3. It needs to be formatted in an easily-readable or interpretable way (standard date format, or seconds since epoch).

**What I've Tried:**

I can call `ntpdate -q my.ntp.server` and get the offset between the local time and the server's time, but that doesn't return the date according to the NTP server; it just returns the offset and the local date.

Is there some easy way/command I can use to say: "Print out the date according to a given NTP server, adjusted for my current timezone"?

Comment: Is parsing the output an option? I mean, if you have your system's time and the offset from the ntp server time, it should be relatively easy to combine the 2 and infer the ntp server's time.

Comment: How? My `awk` skills are rusty...

Comment: I don't have ntpdate on my system, if you post the output, maybe I or someone else can figure it out.

Comment: similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/155772/software-displaying-the-time-of-an-ntp-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl script should do what you need (assuming you don't need precision to the 10<sup>-6</sup> of a second):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Math::Round;

## Get current date (epoch)
my $date=time();

## Get the seconds offset, rounding to the nearest second
my $ntp=nearest(0.1,`ntpdate -q $ARGV[0] | gawk '(\$NF~/sec/){print \$(NF-1)}'`); 

## Get the server's time
my $ntp_date=$date+$ntp;

## Convert to human readable and print
print "The time according to server $ARGV[0] is " . localtime($ntp_date) . "\n";
```

Save the script as check_ntp.pl and run it with the server as an argument:

```
perl ./check_ntp.pl my.ntp.server
```

Comment: Not sure if this actually works.  I set my system time to be several hours off, but `ntpdate` printed `offset -0.000033 sec`.  Perhaps something using `ntpdate -d` and looking at `reference time` is more useful?